# Resize image to X on long edge while preserving ratio

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

How do I resize an image to say 800px on the long edge while preserving the image ratio using rmagick?

Comment: Any code written to answer your question would have absolutely no relation to what you've written because we don't know anything about your code base. Instead, show us a minimal example of your code where you'd like to resize so any answers are relevant to your code.

Comment: I simply stored every filename (incl. absolute path) in an array and I'm doing a `.each do` on it so that every image will be resied. Do you need more? (What exactly?)

Comment: I'd recommend reading the "[How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" page.